# Scale button inside grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have a grid with 4 columns and 2 rows.
Inside each cell of this grid is a custom button (made out of a canvas, rectangle and a textblock grouped into a button control with blend 4).

So basicaly this grid has 8 custom buttons that are all alike in size but just differ from text content.

**Problem:**

When i enlarge my screen the grid and the cells grow with the window size correctly.
The position of the buttons also size correctly. ***But the size of the buttons never changes.***

How to modify the grid/button so the buttons actually grow in size when the screen gets larger?
All settings like width and height are set to auto.

Example of some code of the grid:

```
 <Grid x:Name="gridSubCategories" Margin="15,125,15,50">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="btnTestOne" Content="TestOne" Margin="9.426,29.05,9.425,29.05" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleTestOne}" 
                Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Viewbox as a parent of the button

> Defines a content decorator that can stretch and scale a single child to fill the available space.

```
<Viewbox>
  Child
</Viewbox>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try to use HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" and VerticalAlignment="Stretch" for buttons